# Ionic notification using OneSignal is not working when app is closed

Tags: android, push-notification, ionic3, onesignal, ionic-native

I'm trying to use **Push Notification** to my mobile application, and tried to use [Ionic IO Push](https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/), [PushWoosh](http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/cordova-phonegap), and now [OneSignal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/onesignal/), both with the same problem.

In [One Signal documentation about push notification not being sent](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications-show-successful-but-are-not-being-shown#section-the-app-is-force-stopped), it says that maybe the app is in **Force Closed** state, and, if it is, in the `logcat` you will see this message when trying to send a push notification:

> W/GCM-DMM: broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.onesignal.example (has extras) }

So, to see it, I used the command `adb logcat grep | 'GCM'` to see if my device is sending this message.

And Yes, it is.

It is okay to show it if the app is **Forced Closed**, but the error message appears when the app is **Open** or in **Background** too.

I found it strange, because when the app is Open, or in Background, I can receive Push Notifications, and handle it as I want, even if the error message is displayed in `logcat`, but when I close it, there is no more notification, and the error message keeps appearing in the `logcat`.

#### What I tried?

- In the same [One signal documentation about push notification not being sent](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications-show-successful-but-are-not-being-shown#section-the-app-is-force-stopped), it says that the app can be **Force Closed** with `Swiping away your app while remote debugging it`, so I tried to use `ionic cordova run android --prod --release --device` to test the push notification, and still the same thing happened.
- OneSignal has a [lot of different configuration to send push messages](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications), so I tried many different variation of configuration when sending push notifications, and any of them could reach my device with the app closed, or even change the `logcat` message.
- Installed OneSignal in my app following [One signal instructions](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-sdk-setup), [Ionic instructions](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/onesignal/), and, as I am really desperate, applied [Gradle config of Android SDK](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup) too, and none of them worked.

#### My config

- Config:

  - Ionic CLI: 3.6.0
  - Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
  - @ionic-native/onesignal: 4.1.0
  - Device: Lenovo K5
- Plugin list

  - `ionic cordova plugin list`
  - cordova-plugin-app-event 1.2.0 "Application Events"
  - cordova-plugin-autostart 2.0.1 "Autostart"
  - cordova-plugin-console 1.0.7 "Console"
  - cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
  - cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
  - cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.3 "StatusBar"
  - cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"
  - de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification 0.8.5 "LocalNotification"
  - ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
  - onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.1.2 "OneSignal Push Notifications"